# Is there SSD storage available for Oracle Cloud VM.Standard.E2.1 instance?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I want to know if I can choose somehow SSD storage type for my VM.Standard.E2.1 instance on Oracle Cloud. 
They provide the so-called Block Storage type, though I am not exactly sure it is SSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their [website here says so](https://cloud.oracle.com/storage/block-volume/faq).

> **Are Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Block Volumes using NVMe SSDs in the storage infrastructure?**
>
> Yes. Industry-leading highest performance NVMe solid state drives are used. This high performance, backed by a performance SLA, is enabled without using storage caching.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer provided